# Session 'app': Install failed. Installation failed Rerun

Tags: android, emulation

I am trying to run app on redme 6  but I am getting the following error
Session 'app': Install failed Installation faile Rerun

I have tried to invalidate cache restart did not help

Answer (score 1):

Please follows the step to enable Install via USB option.

Additional setting -> Developer options -> Install via USB = enable

Comment: It's only for redme phone. please check it